# How does EclipseLink handle "proxy entities"?

Tags: java, eclipselink

Our application originally used hibernate, but switching to eclipselink gave us additional caching capabilities and a performance boost. Within eclipselink, we are now facing a strange problem that we can not pin down to a certain feature.

The problem´s symptoms are that in rare cases (after having successfully run the application for hours, days sometimes), when the application is trying to access an entity, it retrieves the entity but not the related entities, even though they are related with an eager relation. Instead, the field of the entity is just null.

While trying to find the reason for this, we found an optimization which worked very well with hibernate, but maybe causes problems with EclipseLink.

The optimization consists of creating proxy entities, which are used if we want to relate two entities without having to load the entity that does not maintain the relation and therefore is not going to be updated.

For example we want to relate a Resource with a ResourceType. We have the id of the ResourceType, but not the whole entity. We load the Resource and set the ResourceType using the setter, but instead of giving it the actual ResourceType entity, we just give it a proxy entity that we create in the following way:

```
public <T extends PersistentRecord> T proxy(Class<T> clazz, String id) {
    if(id == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        try {
            T record = clazz.newInstance();
            record.setId(id);
            return record;
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to create proxy record.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

All entities inherit from the PersistentRecord and all of them have a primary key called entityId. Furthermore, the entities have a tenant id field used with the multi-tenancy feature of eclipse to store different tenant data in the same table. We use both the first level and second level cache of eclipselink by having separate entity manager factories for each tenant and having set

```
<property name="eclipselink.multitenant.tenants-share-emf" value="false"/>
```

in the persistence.xml.

When persisting the above described Resource element with the proxy ResourceType element, what will I get back if I retrieve it again from the cache in another context such as retrieving an element that has the Resource as a field? From what we found out, the ResourceType element is retrieved correctly very often, but in rare cases, we do not retrieve the ResourceType at all. Instead we just get null. To fix it, we then have to access the ResourceType while having our EntityManager session open, which then causes the ResourceType to be loaded.

```
m.getResource().getResourceType()
```

Here, m is another entity that references the Resource with the ResourceType that we stored before.

Any ideas if the proxy elements are an optimization leading to problems is appreciated. Any other related information is welcome. If you need any more information, please do not hesitate to ask.

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like these proxies are interfering with the cache when the entities referencing them are getting merged in to the shared cache.  Try to narrow down what operations are being done (merge/persist) on the entity referencing the proxy entity and if the proxied entity is already in the cache when you proxy it. But for the most part, I would avoid creating your own proxy instances and instead use JPA's find/getReference methods. The entity reference needs to be complete in the shared cache anyway, so using your proxy isn't going to help the application.

Comment: So if I want to do the above described procedure, I should use getReference to get a JPA proxy object to then update the reference at the other object?

Comment: Is there an up-to-date documentation of how the JPA entitymanager methods should be used correctly?